# How to hide text on latest page of document and show it on others on OpenOffice/LibreOffice?

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, openoffice-writer

I need to show different text in footer, e.g. set note "Continued on next page" on footer of all pages except latest one. The task seems simple but I haven't found any docs how to do that...

I tried to create hidden variable outside of footer and set hidden paragraph depending on it, but seems like all [variables](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Variables) in LibreOffice is global for whole document. I tried to create ["text with condition"](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Developing_conditional_content) depended on variable, but it also same for any page. How to do that properly?

Also I would be glad if anyone tell me how to access embed variable with page number.

Comment: Did you try to use a different page style for the last page of your document? This way, you can set different footers.

Answer (score 0):

First, you activate footer in used page template.

Then insert a conditional text, not showing on last page, using:

```
Insert > Fields... > Other... > Document > (Type) Page > (Select) Next page > (Format) Text > (Value) Continued on next page
```

This way text only appears if there is a "next page"

Does this help?